# How to create equal height ListItems in dojox.mobile.EdgeToEdgeList?

Tags: dojo, dojox.mobile

I have a standard `dojox.mobile.EdgeToEdge` list with a set of `dojox.mobile.ListItem`s inside. I need to ensure that each list item is of equal height. See poorly drawn representation below:

Standard `EdgeToEdgeList` with `ListItem`s:

```
+-------------------+
| Standard ListItem |
|-------------------|
| Standard ListItem |
|-------------------|
| Standard ListItem |
|-------------------|
| Standard ListItem |
+-------------------+
```

Standard `EdgeToEdgeList` with **variable height** list items; achieved by setting the `variableHeight` property on the list item:

```
+-------------------+
| Standard ListItem |
|-------------------|
| Standard ListItem |
|-------------------|
| Standard ListItem |
| with some long    |
| text and variable |
| height that wraps |
| to next line      |
|-------------------|
| Standard ListItem |
+-------------------+
```

`EdgeToEdgeList` with equal height list items (smaller list items "take" height of largest):

```
+-------------------+
|                   |
|                   |
| Standard ListItem |
|                   |
|                   |
|-------------------|
|                   |
|                   |
| Standard ListItem |
|                   |
|                   |
|-------------------|
| Standard ListItem |
| with some long    |
| text and variable |
| height that wraps |
| to next line      |
|-------------------|
|                   |
|                   |
| Standard ListItem |
|                   |
|                   |
+-------------------+
```

I'm attempting to replicate the third solution. Is there a standard way to do this?

**Edit:** I failed to mention that I'm constructing the list programmatically, so I don't know the height of the largest item before hand. Could something like this work?

```
var largest = 0;
array.forEach(list.getChildren(), function(child) {
    var childHeight = domStyle.get(child.domNode, 'height');

    largest = (childHeight > largest) ? childHeight : largest;
});

array.forEach(list.getChildren(), function(child) {
    domStyle.set(child.domNode, 'height', largest + 'px');
});
```

This seems kind of "hack-y".

Answer (score 0):

Override the height property in the `.mblListItem` CSS class.

The height is 43px by default I believe.

**Edit:** I think your code would work, but you need to set the `ListItem`'s to be variableHeight so that Dojo calculates how much height to give each one, then take the largest and apply it to each. Similar to what you wrote, but adding in variableHeight, and then taking it away when applying the largest height.

```
var largestHeight = 0;
var list = dijit.byId("list");
dojo.forEach(data, function(record) {
    var listItem = new dojox.mobile.ListItem({
        label: data.label
        variableHeight: true,
    }); 
    list.addChild(listItem); 
    var currentHeight = (dojo.style(listItem.domNode, 'height');
    largestHeight = (currentHeight > largestHeight ? currentHeight : largestHeight);
});

dojo.query('.mblListItem', dojo.byId('list')).forEach(function(node) {
    dojo.removeClass(node, 'mblVariableHeight');
    dojo.style(node, 'height', largestHeight + 'px');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer mccrager. The list is being generated programmatically, so I don' necessarily *know* the height of the biggest list item.